# Orphan Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Is there an idiomatic way to deal with side-effecting `scala.concurrent.Future` whose result is not really needed in the caller (i.e. neither success nor failure will be necessary to calculate the calling method's return value)? For example,

```
object XYZ {
  def log(s: String): Future[Unit] = ???
}
```

Is it correct to simply call `XYZ.log("xyz")` without any callbacks and proceed with the really important tasks? Won't this orphan Future be considered code smell? Any chance for it to be garbage collected before it is executed?

Comment: It is not considered code smell, if the behaviour you want is to "do stuff" while that future is completing that is totally fine.

Comment: That may be fine, the only problem I may see is that if that **Future** never completes _(for whatever reason)_ your application will hang and you wouldn't notice why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Won't this orphan Future be considered code smell?

Not any more than any other discarded non-`Unit` value. Note that some people [*do* consider any discarded value to be a code smell](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/11/24/value-discard.html), which is why `-Ywarn-value-discard` and [`NonUnitStatements` wart](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html) exist.

> Any chance for it to be garbage collected before it is executed?

The `Future` object itself might be garbage collected, but it will submit a task to a thread pool which won't be (because the pool holds a reference to the task). Except cases like

```
def log(s: String): Future[Unit] = Future.just(())
```

of course.

Answer (score 1):

When we have such `Future`s which are not part of main business logic but executed for their side effect, that is, represent a separate concern such as logging, then consider running them on a separate dedicated execution context. For example, create a separate pool with

```
val numOfThreads = 2
val threadPoolForSeparateConcerns = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads, (r: Runnable) => new Thread(r, s"thread-pool-for-separate-concerns-thread-${Random.nextInt(numOfThreads)}"))
val separateConcernsEc = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(threadPoolForSeparateConcerns)
```

and then make sure to pass it in when running separate concerns

```
object XYZ {
  def log(s: String, ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = ???
}

XYZ.log("Failed to calculate 42", separateConcernsEc)
```

By separating main business logic thread pool, from thread pool for side-concerns, we minimise the chances of breaking main business logic through things like resource starvation etc.